# PHP and MySQL Foreign key not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a bit of MySQL using commands through PHP only (without using the phpMyAdmin interface to create the tables) and I'm having a bit of a problem creating Primary and Foreign keys. This is my current code.

```
<?php
$conectar = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
//mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE DataBaseTeste") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DataBaseTeste") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Pergunta("
    . "id_Pergunta INT AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    . "Descricao TEXT,"
    . "Nivel VARCHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_Pergunta),"
    . "FOREIGN KEY(id_Assunto) REFERENCES Assunto(id_Assunto))")Or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Aluno("
    . "id_Aluno INT NOT NULL,"
    . "AlunoNome CHAR,"
    . "Grupo CHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_Aluno))")Or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Assunto("
    . "id_Assunto INT,"
    . "Descricao VARCHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_Assunto))")Or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close();

?>
```

I also tried using this (without the FOREIGN KEY, by just inserting the other table's id):

```
$conectar = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
//mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE DataBaseTeste") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DataBaseTeste") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Pergunta("
    . "id_Pergunta INT AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    . "Descricao TEXT,"
    . "Nivel VARCHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_Pergunta),"
    . "id_Assunto INT)")Or die(mysql_error());
```

The error message I get is this:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY(id_Pergunta)..."

It's probably something pretty stupid but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Replace mysql_* functions with mysqli_*

Comment: ALL functions? because i just restarded everything and it didnt work...

Answer (score 1):

First, try to use lowercase names, I just did it for `PKs`

Then to use `foreign keys` you must add the column name do that table which will hold the `FK`

Also then, you need to use `INNODB`, can't remember if `MyIsam` allows you FK, but I recommend it, note that `INNODB` will create an index for them too.

```
CREATE TABLE assunto(
    id_assunto INT,
    descricao VARCHAR(254),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_assunto)
)ENGINE=INNODB; 

CREATE TABLE aluno(
    id_aluno INT NOT NULL,
    alunoNome CHAR(254),
    grupo CHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_aluno)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE pergunta(
    id_pergunta INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_assunto int,
    descricao TEXT,
    nivel VARCHAR(254),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_pergunta),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_assunto) REFERENCES assunto(id_assunto)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Let me add you a PHP version, **note the execution order**.

```
<?php
$conectar = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
//mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE DataBaseTeste") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DataBaseTeste") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE aluno("
    . "id_aluno INT NOT NULL,"
    . "alunoNome CHAR,"
    . "grupo CHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_aluno))")Or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE assunto("
    . "id_assunto INT,"
    . "descricao VARCHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_assunto))")Or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE Pergunta("
    . "id_pergunta INT AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    . "id_assunto INT AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    . "descricao TEXT,"
    . "Nivel VARCHAR,"
    . "PRIMARY KEY(id_pergunta),"
    . "FOREIGN KEY(id_assunto) REFERENCES assunto(id_assunto))")Or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();
```

This is a working sqlfiddle Mysql 5.1, I use 5.5.32 but show as 5.1 will work too.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/f88b5/3

Comment: I used exacly the code you made tehre, and it created the data base and the "Aluno" table, but everything else didnt work and now this si teh error that appears to me:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY(id_assunto))' at line 1

Comment: I updated my script (not the php version) there where a few extra chars(';') , but I did it from mysql-cli, with MYSQL 5.5.32, try it from the command line, it will be faster then transcribe to your PHP, copy paste will should work

Comment: Yeah i sitll could not find what is going on but you helped alot, at least the database is created and working, thanks alot mate.

Comment: I added a sqlfidle so you can play with it

Comment: thanks alot, it works just fine there but for some reason the php code just dosent understand the primary and foreign key comands

Comment: That is weird, anyway use MySQLi instead of Mysql API, not hard to migrate to Mysqli